# Webdriver FluentWait not ignoring exceptions

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have automated some user flows which go via this page http://www.efinancialcareers.co.uk/search.
When I narrow a search using the left hand-side refine rail, an overlay appears where a user has to wait until the search results are returned. The method waits for the overlay to appear and then waits for it to disappear.

```
public void waitForSRPOverlayToComplete() {

    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(getDriver())
            .withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(TimeoutException.class);

    **// Error occurs here**
    WebElement blockedOverlay = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(By.className("blockOverlay"));
        }
    });

    Wait<WebDriver> wait2 = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(getDriver())
            .withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(TimeoutException.class);

    wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(blockedOverlay));
}
```

On occasion I get a Timeout exception as the element (blockOverlay) is not found. I have observed the page when this occurs and the overlay does appear but I think sometimes when the search is very fast the above method misses it. **I don’t understand why I get a technical error as I have told the fluent wait to ignore them.**

This is the code to make the overlay appear:

```
$('body').block({
            message: $('#loaderEl'),
            css: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                border: "none",
                color: '#333333',
                fontWeight: 'bolder',
                top: ($(window).height() - $('#loaderEl').height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px"
            },
            overlayCSS: {
                backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8'
            },
            centerY: false
        });
```

And to remove it

```
$('body').unblock();
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for     com.efinancialcareers.myefc.desktop.BasePage$6@548238e0
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6bedf70ff9f22c647788f9fe9c8d22210e2',     time: '2013-08-17 12:46:41'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"blockOverlay"}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't suppress `TimeoutException` when the `FluentWait` actually times out. That's simply the nature of the API. If this is an exception you truly want to ignore, you need to catch the `TimeoutException`.

Also, as a side note, attempting to poll for the condition every nanosecond is likely counterproductive. You should probably extend your polling interval to something like every 200 or 250 milliseconds.

Comment: Every nanosecond? Now I know one more way to build a fire.

Answer (score 3):

A big thank you to Jim Evans for giving me the critical clue I needed to know why this problem occurs.

I decided to go further by digging into the FluentWait code (Java 1.8 or higher) to see why the TimeoutException is thrown even if you request it to not be thrown.

**Typical example of FluentWait:**

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        FluentWait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = (WebElement) wait.until(new Function() {
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(Object input) {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

We look at the `until` method of FluentWait because that is the method which actually starts the waiting process. Its likely that all the exception handling/throwing logic might be there. All other method calls of FluentWait, such as `withTimeout`, `ignoring` etc. actually create "settings" for a FluentWait object. They do not perform any actions like waiting or running some code etc.

Let's look at the [documentation for "until"](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until-com.google.common.base.Function-). The last line tells us that the method throws a TimeoutException. So, the until method is NOT supposed to ignore TimeoutException even if you requested for it.

```
Throws:
TimeoutException - If the timeout expires.
```

We now quickly look at the code of FluentWait to understand why "until" does not ignore TimeoutException.

```
  public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue) {
    long end = clock.laterBy(timeout.in(MILLISECONDS));
    Throwable lastException = null;
    while (true) {
      try {
        V value = isTrue.apply(input);
        if (value != null && Boolean.class.equals(value.getClass())) {
          if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(value)) {
            return value;
          }
        } else if (value != null) {
          return value;
        }
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        lastException = propagateIfNotIgnored(e);
      }

      // Check the timeout after evaluating the function to ensure conditions
      // with a zero timeout can succeed.
      if (!clock.isNowBefore(end)) {
        String message = messageSupplier != null ?
            messageSupplier.get() : null;

        String toAppend = message == null ?
            " waiting for " + isTrue.toString() : ": " + message;

        String timeoutMessage = String.format("Timed out after %d seconds%s",
            timeout.in(SECONDS), toAppend);
        throw timeoutException(timeoutMessage, lastException);
      }

      try {
        sleeper.sleep(interval);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new WebDriverException(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

The while block will:

1. return the "value" variable, OR
2. propagate any exception which you did not request to be ignored. (refer to the propagateIfNotIgnored method call. The name makes it obvious and you can see the code as well to confirm.)

The if block will run when an exception is not propagated. It will throw a TimeoutException if timeout occurs. So, that is the bit of code responsible for the timeout exception.

Comment: I'm not sure how I see where the code is "complicated." When the timeout is evaluated (`if (!clock.isNowBefore(end))`), if the timeout has expired, throw a `TimeoutException`, which is the value returned by another method in the class creatively named `timeoutException()`. The method takes as an argument the actual exception to propagate, which has been caught by the previous exception handling block. Note carefully that this block of code is outside any try-catch, and as such, is not affected by the code that ignores exceptions of a given type.

Comment: @JimEvans - Thanks. I reacted too soon. I kept calm and just scanned the code quickly and edited my answer. The code is not as hard to understand as I thought.